# Why does docker-compose depends on working directory?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

When calling docker-compose in different directories, I get conflict errors and problems with networking:

**Problem with conflicts**

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"
    container_name: redis
```

I. create and start docker container by docker-compose => OK

```
$ docker-compose  up --force-recreate -d
Creating redis ... done
```

II. recreate and start docker container by docker-compose => OK

```
$ docker-compose  up --force-recreate -d 
Recreating redis ... done
```

III. copy docker-compose.yml to other directory.
   Then try to recreate from other directory => ERROR

```
$ cp docker-compose.yml  red2/
$ cd red2/
$ docker-compose  up --force-recreate -d

Creating redis ... error

ERROR: for redis  Cannot create container for service redis: Conflict. The container name "/redis" is already in use by container "1ba060b545f716731ac1c5992b680e4d4b3639fc0ffeb291899c712f0839d23a". You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name.
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

**Different Networks**

Containers created from docker-compose in different directories also do not share the same network.

```
$ docker network ls
NETWORK ID          NAME                       DRIVER              SCOPE
4a4af52e89cd        red2_default               bridge              local
57695428bd9d        redis_default              bridge              local
```

**Usecase**

My usecase for that szenario:

- Call docker-compose from different deployment jobs.
- Start containers for testing

**Questions**

1. Why is there the directory dependency? Is there an option to switch it off?
2. Does `docker ps` show which directory was used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer for 1:

The directory name is used as the default project name.
You should better specify the project name:

```
docker-compose -p myproject up --force-recreate -d
```

Question 2 still open